# ExtJS REST configuration gives Model name to ID

Tags: rest, post, extjs, java-server

I am working with **ExtJS 5.1.1** and getting an error during `POST` process to Java server. Inside the DB there are several fields and `ID` is keyfield and generate automatically by server. I need only 3 fields to display and create/update/delete; **firstName, lastName, email**. I can't configure the ExtJS for POST to not touch ID, only pass those three fields via Form Panel.

Here is *Request Payload* of one sample record. As you will notice it gave name of Model to `ID`:

```
{"firstName":"New","lastName":"Record","email":"new@record.com","id":"Employee.model.EmployeeMdl-2"}
```

Therefore Java-Spring server response this message:

```
"Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type int from String "Employee.model.EmployeeMdl-1": not a valid Integer value↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@ae6769; line: 1, column: 74]
```

The `PUT` process works very well! Could you please give any idea for `POST`?

Here is Model snippet:

```
Ext.define('Employee.model.EmployeeMdl', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'lastName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'email', type: 'string'}
    ],
    idProperty: 'id',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'      
        },
        api: {
            read: 'http://ip:port/orest/employee',
            create: 'http://ip:port/orest/employee',
            update: 'http://ip:port/orest/employee'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            allowSingle: true,
            encode: false,
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide to the model a specific way to generate the ID.

What I can recommend if integers are required is [`Ext.data.identifier.Negative`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.identifier.Negative.html). You would put the full class name into the requires section of the model and then just add the config [`identifier: 'negative'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-identifier) in the model.

Of course this means that you would have to tell the backend that negative ids indicate new entries.

Comment: Dear @Alexander, I have configure the Model as you told; included to requires and then defined identifier. So now `POST` and `PUT` both works well. I have checked successful `POST` record's id on DB and it saved with **ID: -1**. Here we use Java-Spring server, do you have any idea for backend to  recognize this id as provisionally generated and convert it.

Comment: I don't know how the Spring framework works, you would have to ask that in a new question with spring framework tag. It is not possible to have multiple records with the same id in ExtJS, e.g. an undefined id or zero.

Comment: Ok! dear @Alexander. That configuration works very well. Again thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: Hi again @Alexander! I will have another question, just noticed that this configuration keeps reset ID generator for each time when i close the window and open again. Therefore it keeps always 'post' with the ID: -1 and of course thats getting problem. Is there anyway to set it to increase ID?

Comment: I just tried [Sequential identifier](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.identifier.Sequential.html) and set `increment` config but when its reloading the browser, it gets back to number that i defined. :(

Comment: You should use the -1, -2, ... only for the transmission of new records. They should be saved in the backend using positive ids, and the saved records returned to the client with the new ids, so that the frontend can update the ids in the store.